# The shared library class invoked event. How to catch this event in application App.xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Here is code example. I see "SharedLib MainPageRequest: " in console, but not "sl_MainPageRequestEventHandler:" It looks I missed something.

Shared Library

```
public class SharedLib
    {
        delegate void MainPageRequestEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event EventHandler MainPageRequest;
        public ApplicationDataContainer localSettings { get; set; }

        public SharedLib()
        {
            this.localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        }

        public void init_MainPageRequest()
        {
            MainPageRequest?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Debug.WriteLine("SharedLib MainPageRequest: ");   
        }        
    }
```

App.xml

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
        public ApplicationDataContainer localSettings { get; set; }
        public SharedLib sl = new SharedLib();

        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
            this.localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            this.sl.MainPageRequest += sl_MainPageRequestEventHandler;
        }

    private void sl_MainPageRequestEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("sl_MainPageRequestEventHandler:");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I assume `init_MainPageRequest()` is called when the `SharedLib` instance is being constructed (correct me if my assumption is wrong).**

This is because when `init_MainPageRequest()` is executed, the event `MainPageRequest` remains null, meaning that it has still not yet registered.

Let us see the order of executions in the constructor of the `App` class.

This line is a variable declaration and initialization, it actually takes place *before* the body of the constructor of the `App` class, where you wire up the event with the event handler.

```
public SharedLib sl = new SharedLib();
```

Further explanation on [Constructor execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645606(v=vs.71).aspx).

> It is useful to think of instance variable initializers and constructor initializers as statements that are automatically inserted before the constructor-body.